# How do I display a graph theory problem?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If I have several nodes and the distances that they have between one another,
how do get Mathematica to display this as a graph?

And also maybe define this graph in such a way that I can then use things like FindShortestTour.

So for a simple example say I had points A,B,C, where:

the distance from A to B is 10

the distance from A to C is 20

the distance from B to C is 15.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a somewhat random example to get your started:

```
g = Graph[
  Range[4], {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 1 <-> 4}, 
  VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[4] -> CharacterRange["A", "D"]],
  EdgeWeight -> {10, 20, 15, 30, 10}, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FindShortestPath[g, 3, 4]
FindShortestTour[g]

(* Out:
  {3, 1, 4}
  {75, {1, 4, 2, 3, 1}}
*)
```